# How to print Vue objects row by row

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue application and I am trying to display each 'object' in its own table row. However, I can only get it to display each object in one column or I can get it to a point where each element is in its own row (image below). How would I make it so '0 BTC AUD 14,745.3' is in the first row and then the next object '1 ETH AUD 312.14' is displayed in the second row. I am new to Vue and was wondering if anyone was able to help me out

I have attached an image below as well as my current code, thank you!

[image: example picture]

```
<template>
<div class="main">
  <div id="container" v-for="(index) in coin" :key="index">
    <table class="coins">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>{{ index }}</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
var limit = 20

export default {
  name: 'ex',
  data: () => ({
    coin: []
  }),

  created () {
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=' + limit + '&tsym=AUD')
      .then(response => {
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          this.coin.push(i, response.data.Data[i].CoinInfo.Name, response.data.Data[i].DISPLAY.AUD.PRICE)
          // console.log(this.coin[i])
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you are pushing data into your coin array, because here in every iteration you are pushing three items (an index, a coin name and a value) into the array but what you want to do is push a single item (an array or object) containing all this information. For code clarity also change the name of the `coin` array into `coins`. Something like this should work:

```
this.coins.push([i, response.data.Data[i].CoinInfo.Name, response.data.Data[i].DISPLAY.AUD.PRICE])
```

Then change the iteration in your template. First thing change the v-for to something like this:

```
<div id="container" v-for="(coin, index) in coins" :key="index">
```

and then when you print the content:

```
<tbody>
     <td>{{ coin[0] }}</td>
     <td>{{ coin[1] }}</td>
     <td>{{ coin[2] }}</td>
</tbody>
```

I didn't test this, but I hope the general idea is enough to get you on the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

maybe change how did you create this object

instead do that:

```
this.coin.push(i, response.data.Data[i].CoinInfo.Name, response.data.Data[i].DISPLAY.AUD.PRICE)
```

Do something like that

```
const coinObject = {
  index: i,
  name:response.data.Data[i].CoinInfo.Name,
  price: response.data.Data[i].DISPLAY.AUD.PRICE
}
this.coin.push(coinObject);
```

and then you can loop like that in your template:

```
 <div id="container" v-for="(coinItem, index) in coin" :key="index">
    <table class="coins">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>{{ coinItem.index }}</td>
        <td>{{ coinItem.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ coinItem.price }}</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```